# How Can I Update The Products Variants Stock Using The PHP in Shopify?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have created a shopify app for updating the stock of the products. It is updating the stock but it is not updating the variants stock.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['stockupdate'])){
        $start = 0;
        $queuestart = 50;
        $sqlb = "SELECT pending_num FROM stock_queue where id = '1'";
        $resultb = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);
        $rowb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultb);
        $queuestart = $rowb['pending_num'];
        echo 'Please Wait Stock Update In Process... '.$queuestart.' -- <br><br>';
        $sqla = "SELECT count(*) FROM csv_new";
        $resulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
        $rowa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta);
        $totaldataindb = $rowa['count(*)'];
        if($queuestart<$totaldataindb){
            $start = $queuestart;
            $queuestart+=50;
            $qrupdate = "UPDATE stock_queue set pending_num='".$queuestart."' WHERE id ='1'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $qrupdate);
            $sqlorder = "SELECT * FROM csv_new where id between $start and $queuestart";
            $resultorder = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlorder);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultorder) > 0) {
                    while($roworder = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultorder)) {
                        if($roworder['product_name_in_csv']!='' && $roworder['product_name_in_csv']!='eancode'){
                            $query = array('query'=>'{
                                products(first:1, query:"sku:'.$roworder['product_name_in_csv'].'") {
                                    edges {
                                        node {
                                                id
                                                title
                                                variants(first:20){
                                                    edges{
                                                      node{
                                                        title
                                                        inventoryItem{
                                                          id
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ');
  $subscription = shopify_gql_call($token, $shp3, $query);
  $subscriptionres = json_decode($subscription['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  foreach ($subscriptionres as $subscriptionval) {
   foreach ($subscriptionval['products']['edges'] as $keysub => $valuesub) {
    foreach ($valuesub['node']['variants']['edges'] as $key1 => $value1) {
     if($roworder['stock_variants']==$value1['node']['title'] || $value1['node']['title']=='Default Title'){
           $getinventroyid = str_replace("gid://shopify/InventoryItem/","",$value1['node']['inventoryItem']['id']);
            $inlvl_array2 = array('inventory_item_ids'=>$getinventroyid);
           $inlvlTag2 = shopify_call($token, $shp3, "/admin/api/2021-07/inventory_levels.json", $inlvl_array2,'GET');
           $inlvlTag2 = json_decode($inlvlTag2['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                                           
         $inlvl_array = array(
             "location_id" => $inlvlTag2['inventory_levels'][0]['location_id'],
             "inventory_item_id" => $inlvlTag2['inventory_levels'][0]['inventory_item_id'],
              "available" => $roworder['new_stock_csv']
         );
 $inlvlTag = shopify_call($token, $shp3, "/admin/api/2022-07/inventory_levels/set.json", $inlvl_array,'POST');
 $inlvlTag = json_decode($inlvlTag['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
 }
}
 }
  }
}
 } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
               
            ?>
            <script>
             window.location.reload();
            </script>
            <?php
               
        }
        echo "Process Completed!! <br> <br> <br> <button class='updatestockbtn' id='btnbackhome'>Back to home page</button>";
   
    }
```

Comment: I think it is hilarious that you are going through all this trouble and using the API 2021-07. You might want to try 2023-04 and stop pretending it is 2021. That stuff is old and deprecated and not going to help you much moving forward.